# Toolset to develop iOS apps on Windows

Tags: windows, software-development, ios

My company wants to create iOS apps, but they don't want to spend a lot of money on a Mac, so they want to know if it's possible to create iOS apps on Windows.

I have never worked with an Apple product before, so I really don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://learnappmaking.com/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-pc/) mentions some possibilities. The software-oriented solutions are:

- Use **virtualization software**, like the free [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/); you'll only need to purchase macOS, not an entire Mac. You'll essentially have a Mac running on your Windows machine, where you can install all regular software required for iOS development (i.e. the Xcode toolset).
- **Cross-platform development tools**: frameworks like [Xamarin Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/), [PhoneGap / Cordova](http://www.businessofapps.com/news/apache-cordova-adobe-phonegap-know-real-differences/), [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) and [Appcelerator](https://www.appcelerator.com/) let you develop once (at least in theory) and deploy your app to multiple operating systems, including Android and iOS. Often, you'll still need a Mac to build and distribute iOS apps, but depending on the framework, cloud services can help with this process. If you're familiar with HTML/JavaScript/CSS or with C#, this will even save you time learning a new language (Swift or Objective-C) which is required to develop native iOS apps.